# Viewclient touch() is working as a long tap , it should work as click?

Tags: monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I am testing a Gallery application of android 4.0.3 using monkeyrunner with androidviewclient and when I am trying click on any album with touch() function of AVC it is selecting the album . It should open a album.
My code for opening a album is

```
   MonkeyRunner.sleep(3)
   vc=ViewClient(device,serialNo)
   firstAlbum = vc.findViewById('id/no_id/1')
   firstAlbum.touch(MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

please let me know if i am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that your album has **uniqueId** '`id/no_id/1`'. You can verify it using `dump.py`. If I run `dump.py --uniqueId` on 4.0.3 Gallery I obtain

```
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView NO_ID None id/no_id/1
   android.widget.LinearLayout NO_ID None id/no_id/2
      android.view.ViewStub id/action_mode_bar_stub None id/action_mode_bar_stub
      android.widget.FrameLayout NO_ID None id/no_id/3
         android.widget.TextView id/title Gallery id/title
      android.widget.FrameLayout id/content None id/content
         android.widget.RelativeLayout id/root None id/root
            android.widget.GridView id/albums None id/albums
               android.widget.LinearLayout NO_ID None id/no_id/4
                  com.android.camera.GalleryPickerItem id/thumbnail None id/thumbnail
                  android.widget.TextView id/title All pictures (3) id/title/1
               android.widget.LinearLayout NO_ID None id/no_id/5
                  com.android.camera.GalleryPickerItem id/thumbnail None id/thumbnail/1
                  android.widget.TextView id/title Download (3) id/title/2
```

so, I guess you want the first album, then I would use:

```
vc = ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit())
firstAlbum = vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(re.compile('All pictures \(\d+\)'))
firstAlbum.touch()
```

or (as oneliner):

```
ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()).findViewWithTextOrRaise(re.compile('All pictures \(\d+\)')).touch()
```

using a regular expression you can select the album, the one with **All pictures** title independently of the number of pictures listed in the title.

Comment: Thanks for reply but issue is not with the view ID, issue is with the touch() method, when I am using touch(UP), touch is not working , for touch(DOWN) it's select the album and when I am using touch(DOWN_AND_UP) it's doing the same thing select the album, it should open the album. BDW I'got the solution for opening the album you can find it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660496/device-touch-is-not-working-properly-for-gallery-application

Comment: I don't understand what's your problem with opening the albums. See this precise example at https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/AndroidViewClient/examples/gallery-select-album.py

Comment: Actually I don't want to select the album I want to open the album so for opening the album I am using the touch() command, but it's working as long tap my album got selected. I hope you've checked the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660496/device-touch-is-not-working-properly-for-gallery-application

Comment: I'm running the example and see how the album opens. Can you explain exactly what you are expecting and what do you mean by "open"?

Comment: Hey milano thanks for your reply but your example is not working in my gallery app. and "Open" means touch on any album should display the content of the albums.

Comment: Same issue with the emulator.

Comment: Please add some screenshots of what you expect and what you obtain

Comment: Sorry Dtmilano but I can not upload the Screenshots as I don't have  enough reputation too upload images. I need 20 to upload the images.

Comment: Use flickr, picasa, dropbox, google drive, wahtever, then link the images.